# Second Segue when pushed not showing navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

Have two segue in my storyboard. One segue shows navigation bar and navigation item when pushed but second segue doesn't shows navigation bar when pushed

This my code for pushing second segue

```
- (IBAction)ReadAction:(id)sender {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];

 }


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

    // Get destination view
    PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController];
}
}
```

In the storyboard navigationbar and navigation bar title is showing for both segue in storyboard and navigationcontroller is set as rootviewcontroller that is why it is showing in first segue but i wonder why it is not showing only for second segue when execute

Edit:

Solved little bit but still have problem

The view controller which i was trying to push

In that view controller had code like this

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
//[self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

When i commented out this statement from above code then it shows navigation bar and backbuttonitem that is what i was looking for

```
 [self presentViewController:page animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

but now after commenting it doesn't displays pageviewcontroller in the pushed view controller.

Now how can i display pageviewcontroller.

Edit:

Just added

```
[self.view addSubview:page.view];
```

but now another problem pageviewcontroller is displaying with navigation bar and all that but  now not turning pages over using curl effect with previous commented statement it was turning pages over

Help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to set the navigation controller

Comment: but in the storyboard navigationbar and navigation bar title is showing and navigationcontroller is set as rootviewcontroller that is why it is showing in first segue but i wonder why it is not showing in second segue when execute

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should work for your needs. One pushes and one presents simply.

```
 PDFViewController *pdfviewController = [segue destinationViewController];

 [self.navigationController presentViewController:pdfviewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfviewController animated:YES];
```

Try both.

Comment: then replace with the follwing [self.navigationController presentViewController:pdfviewController animated:YES];

Comment: but i have set navigation controller as rootview controller in the storyboard and navigation bar is howing in storyboard but not when i execute for the second one

Comment: getting this message when using this statement NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported

Comment: remove [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender]; and under the IBAction just put the code above to push. You could just change the rootviewcontroller to the updated pdf vc.